# How to start with Cocos2D Box2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i want to learn 2D gaming using Cocos2D/Box2D on iPhone...
Gaming demands lots of things to be under the understanding before you actually dive in like physics/geomerical concepts...how to really start with it??

Answer (score 2):

Ray Wenderlich has some excellent tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

More specifically:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls